# How to make a program use Windows 10 window position snapping

Tags: windows-10

A music program that I use (Propellerhead's Reason) has multiple windows, and I use a 3 window setup on 2 monitors.

The windows of this program do not remember their position between sessions when using Win10 window position snapping features.

In Win10, if you take a window by title bar and pull it to the left side edge, it will snap that window to the left half of the screen. You can do the same thing with WinKey + LeftArrow.

The snaps will operate and complete as expected, but they're not saved for the next time the program is opened. Manually moving the windows into an acceptable position is saved. But since I wind up moving these windows around a lot, that very much defeats the purpose of the shortcuts.

Is there a way to ***force*** a program to be aware of these window positions? Or some kind of alternative?

Comment: It is entirely up to an application to keep track of where it last was when it was closed.  There a third-party Window management software that likely will sharif your needs that exist (none that I can recommend or even mention though but aware they exist)

Comment: I'd ask Propellerheads, or just see if there's a recent update that addresses it. It's not a Windows issue, it's an app issue. [I'm on Mac so I can't test latest Win version]